# Replacing NA's with values of the same column

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
NAME             ROLENAME        NUMBER DIRECTORS   COMMITTEE         YEAR      TOTAL OTHER BOARDS
Brown            Member          10                 Audit             2006      8
Brown            NA              7                  Legal             2006      8
Brown            Member          NA                 Audit             2007      8
Brown            Director        7                  Legal             2007      NA
Chapman          Chairman        4                  Compensation      2008      5
Chapman          Specialist      NA                 Corporate         2008      NA
Chapman          NA              4                  Compensation      2009      5
Chapman          Specialist      6                  Corporate         2009      5
```

I only show a bit of the complete dataset. And for both people I have more years than you can see above. And I want the NAs to be replaced with the 'obvious' numbers and strings. So that it looks like this:

```
NAME             ROLENAME        NUMBER DIRECTORS   COMMITTEE         YEAR      TOTAL OTHER BOARDS
Brown            Member          10                 Audit             2006      8
Brown            Director        7                  Legal             2006      8
Brown            Member          10                 Audit             2007      8
Brown            Director        7                  Legal             2007      8
Chapman          Chairman        4                  Compensation      2008      5
Chapman          Specialist      6                  Corporate         2008      5
Chapman          Chairman        4                  Compensation      2009      5
Chapman          Specialist      6                  Corporate         2009      5
```

I really have no clue if I have to do something with an 'if-function' because there are easy ways to rename/replace the NAs. Hope anyone can help me out.

Comment: What are the "obvious" numbers and names?

Comment: Well, I really simplified the dataset. For "Brown" the sequal continiuous for 8 years for example. Thus for 8 years he is in two committees in which he is Member (Audit) or Director (Legal)

Answer (score 2):

You could use tidyr's `fill`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~NAME, ~ROLENAME, ~NUMBER_DIRECTORS, ~COMMITTEE, ~YEAR, ~TOTAL_OTHER_BOARDS,
  "Brown", "Member", 10, "Audit", 2006, 8,
  "Brown", NA, 7, "Legal", 2006, 8,
  "Brown", "Member", NA, "Audit", 2007, 8,
  "Brown", "Director", 7, "Legal", 2007, NA,
  "Chapman", "Chairman", 4, "Compensation", 2008, 5,
  "Chapman", "Specialist", NA, "Corporate", 2008, NA,
  "Chapman", NA, 4, "Compensation", 2009, 5,
  "Chapman", "Specialist", 6, "Corporate", 2009, 5
)

df |> 
  arrange(NAME, COMMITTEE) |> # optional
  group_by(NAME, COMMITTEE) |> 
  fill(ROLENAME, NUMBER_DIRECTORS, TOTAL_OTHER_BOARDS, .direction = "updown") |> 
  ungroup() # if needed
#> # A tibble: 8 × 6
#>   NAME    ROLENAME   NUMBER_DIRECTORS COMMITTEE     YEAR TOTAL_OTHER_BOARDS
#>   <chr>   <chr>                 <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>              <dbl>
#> 1 Brown   Member                   10 Audit         2006                  8
#> 2 Brown   Member                   10 Audit         2007                  8
#> 3 Brown   Director                  7 Legal         2006                  8
#> 4 Brown   Director                  7 Legal         2007                  8
#> 5 Chapman Chairman                  4 Compensation  2008                  5
#> 6 Chapman Chairman                  4 Compensation  2009                  5
#> 7 Chapman Specialist                6 Corporate     2008                  5
#> 8 Chapman Specialist                6 Corporate     2009                  5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>